# How do i use a xsl:variable as another variable's name

Tags: xml, xslt

What im looking to do is put a xsl variable's value and set it as a new variable's name.

My Problem:

There is an entry in an xml file (that i dont have control over) that is a long string of search values. It looks something like this:

```
jobSearch=12345;nameSearch=Joe;colorSearch=Blue
```

The problem is that the terms don't always appear in the same order or appear at all, sometimes it can be:

```
colorSearch=Blue;jobSearch=12345;nameSearch=Joe
```

or even just:

```
jobSearch=12345
```

I can split the string into its indiviual components but i cant seem to figure out how to link the search type to the search value. I would like to call upon these variables later in my xsl by the search type. I thought a could maybe do this in a call template loop but then when i left that the variables would be out of scope. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Edit: I am using XSLT 1.0 and in terms of accessing the terms later in looking to do a key-value pair as Daniel Haley stated just in 1.0

Comment: I am afraid you might be going about this the wrong way, as such a thing is not possible in XSLT. If you give a bit more detail about what you are trying to achieve (rather than just 'how'), then we may able to suggest an alternate approach. Thank you!

Comment: Could you clarify what "*call upon these variables later in my xsl by the search type*" means? -- Also please state which version of XSLT you are using.

Comment: "*in terms of accessing the terms later in looking to do a key-value pair*" That doesn't mean anything. You already *have* an array of  key-value pairs. The only problem is that it's not convenient to access the array in its present form. So the question is what's more efficient: spending efforts to convert the array to something that may be more usable, or leaving it as is and seeing how to extract what you need from it - when you need it.

Comment: Michael you are spot on. I was so caught up in making it into a more usable form that i didn't think about the fact that its already in a key-value pair. I can just search the string when i needed a certain value by using contains() to check to see if its there then extract the value after it.

Comment: Good. Just to clarify: I didn't express an opinion regarding which is preferable. I only said we need to understand how it's going to be used before we can form such opinion.

Comment: What xslt processor are you using? For example I work with XSLT 1.0 in microsoft environment so I can use [msxsl extensions](https://books.google.sk/books?id=2J66V7CHn8QC&pg=PA414&lpg=PA414&dq=xsl+msxsl+extensions&source=bl&ots=zRY6UdEtRx&sig=ACfU3U203WYXDPh7rwJOO9MX3HkyVHHeiQ&hl=sk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj6qqz01qXnAhXBKVAKHZ6AA8UQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=xsl%20msxsl%20extensions&f=false). That allows you to call functions from higher xslt versions or [define own functions in other languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/script-blocks-using-msxsl-script).

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Instead of inventing language features that don't exist, tell us what problem you want to solve and we can tell you how to solve it.

Comment: Yea i figured it didn't work that way, sorry. I updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: For the record, my answer was an answer to a completely different question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question; you're trying to get a key-value pair for each of the "search types" in the string, right? So "colorSearch" = "blue", "jobSearch" = "12345", and "nameSearch" = "Joe". Correct?

You didn't specify what version of XSLT, so here is an example showing 2 ways of doing this. One is by creating XML you can query later. The other is by creating a `map`. The first method works in XSLT 2.0 and 3.0. The second method only works in XSLT 3.0. (I used Saxon-PE for testing.)

**XML Input**

```
<example>jobSearch=12345;nameSearch=Joe;colorSearch=Blue</example>
```

**XSLT** (Shows creating the key-value pairs and then referencing them.)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs map">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="possible-types" select="('jobSearch','nameSearch',
        'colorSearch')"/>

    <!--METHOD 1-->
    <!--XSLT 2.0-->
    <xsl:variable name="searchTypes">
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,';')">
            <xsl:element name="{tokenize(.,'=')[1]}">
                <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(.,'=')[2]"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>        
    </xsl:variable>

    <!--METHOD 2-->
    <!--XSLT 3.0-->
    <xsl:variable name="type-map" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)" 
        select="map:new(
        for $type in tokenize(/*,';') 
        return 
        map{tokenize($type,'=')[1] := tokenize($type,'=')[2]}
        )"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <results>
            <xsl:for-each select="$possible-types">
                <search-type name="{.}" 
                    method1value="{$searchTypes/*[name()=current()]}" 
                    method2value="{$type-map(current())}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </results>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<results>
   <search-type name="jobSearch" method1value="12345" method2value="12345"/>
   <search-type name="nameSearch" method1value="Joe" method2value="Joe"/>
   <search-type name="colorSearch" method1value="Blue" method2value="Blue"/>
</results>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking to do. Unfortunately i didn't state this in the problem but I'm working with XSLT 1.0. Is it possible with this version?